# How to render a list without a render engine in javascript?

Tags: html, node.js, express

No render engine, no framework other than express.

We want to render any list from a database query without the help of a render engine.

What is the bare code equivalent of a render engine for data lists?

This is an example with pug, then with html :

app.js

---

```
collection.query(q, function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({
            error: err
        });
        return;
    }

    console.log("Got docs: ",docs);

    res.render('layout', {
        data : docs
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<ul type="1">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

How do you code this for rendering without pug, with data coming from query response ?

```
ul
    each item in data
        li=item.name
```

Comment: Just.. do what you already said? If you don't want any frameworks or render engines, etc, then (a) why are you showing a .pug file (which is a template, requiring a pug render engine) and (b) just generate plain text HTML and send that as response?

Comment: If you're generating html like this, you'll soon run into the same problems that the creators of those template engines encountered which prompted them to design template engines in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const createList = items => `<ol>${items.map(i => `<li>${i}<li/>`).join("")}<ol/>`;

collection.query(q, function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({
            error: err
        });
        return;
    }

    console.log("Got docs: ",docs);

    res.send(createList(docs))

});
```

That's using arrow functions and template literals, you can change the arrow functions to normal `functions` and the template literals into string concatenated by `+` if you are using a older version of nodejs.

Comment: Here, if someone provide the answer to your question, you can mark the answer as correct, just saying (@Conan).

Comment: you are passing undefined as items, maybe you need to check the docs variable